# handle info from select box

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<form name="votos" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
     <?php $categorias=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM categoria") or die (mysql_error()); ?>
     <?php while($cat=mysql_fetch_array($categorias)){
     echo "<h5>".$cat[0]." - ".$cat[1]."</h5>";
     $nomeados=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nomeados WHERE cod_categoria='$cat[0]'") or die(mysql_error());
     ?>
     <div class="styled-select">
     <select name="voto">
     <option value=""></option>
     <?php
     while($nom=mysql_fetch_array($nomeados)){
        $nomes=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT nome FROM logins WHERE cod_login='$nom[0]'")) or die (mysql_error()); 
        ?>

     <option value="<?php echo $nom[0]; ?>"><?php echo $nomes[0]; ?></option>


     <?php
     }
     ?></select></div>
     <?php }
     ?>
     <input type="submit" class="botao" value="" name="submit" />
     </form>
```

The code shows all the categories with the nomenies in a select box.
The thing is that the select box goes to post with the same name. I don't know how to get the information from all of the select boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have more elements with the same name you can post them as an array

```
 <select name="voto[]">
```

and than you get it in php

```
$votos = $_POST['voto']
foreach($votos as $voto){
  //do what you need to do
}
```

and it's an array with all the values